# How to test google play in app review API is working?

Tags: android, api, unity-game-engine, testing, google-play

I have implemented Google in-app review API to one of my games and it worked. And lately, I added the API to my new game precisely the same way.

But now I can't see the review pop-up showing in the internal test of the game. I can't find a way of testing it. I don't get any errors in the code. I am using Unity by the way. How can I test if it's working or not? If it's not working why is it?

Maybe it did show up and I missed out. If I missed out it is not gonna show up again because of google's policy about it. Please give me some advice about this issue if you know anything.

Answer (score -1):

you can test in-app review. Please check the link to know more.

https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/test

Comment: If you had read my question carefully, you would have seen that I already mentioned that I was doing internal testing. I have already read this article. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).